# How to get the day and month with two digits in ADF Data flow?

Tags: datetime, dataflow, azure-data-factory

I am trying to name my tsv file as "{test}*{year}*{month}*{day}" in ADF Data Flow.
Here is the Expression:
"test+{year(toDate($windowStartTime))}+{month(toDate($windowStartTime))}*{dayOfMonth(toDate($windowStartTime))}.tsv"

When set parameter windowStartTime to "2021+01+01", then it became "test+2021+1+1.tsv".How can I convert it to "test+2021+01+01.tsv" that month(01) and day(01) both have two digits?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the year() and month() functions inside a toString() with formatter to pad with a 0. Here is an example:

toString(month(toDate('2021/01/01','yyyy/MM/dd')),'00')

Answer (score 0):

Convert your parameter/variable to ‘yyyy-MM-dd’ format and replace ‘-‘with ‘+’.

Use **concat()** function to add all the string values as below.

`@concat('test','+',replace(formatDateTime(variables('starttime'),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'-','+'),'.tsv')`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Got it! Thanks!!!